# Why is an unassigned adapter showing up in vSwitch "Teaming and failover" order?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

On two out of three ESXi 6 hosts there is an unused adapter showing up in the Teaming and failover section of a vSwitch even though that adapter is not assigned to the vSwitch (see screenshots below).

These are standard not distributed vSwitches. On one host it is vSwitch3, on the other it is vSwitch4. In both cases the vSwitch in question is used for SAN traffic. In both cases it is the second physical NIC (vmnic1).

FWIW, on the third host that doesn't exhibit this issue, vmnic1 belongs to the vSwitch used for the SAN.

This is a production environment so at this stage I have only looked, I haven't changed anything.

My main question is why is it showing up when it doesn't even belong to the vSwitch?

I don't think it's causing any issues (seeing as it is unused anyway) but I'm wondering if it suggest there may be additional configuration issues? Is there anything else I should be checking or looking out for?

[Manage adapter settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tXmR.png)

[Teaming settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6P5J.png)

Comment: Geez. Why do you have so many adapters in these servers? I don't think this is a problem, though.

Comment: That's a good question @ewwhite! I'm guessing a good salesperson or that was the bundle Dell was offering to schools...They each have four built in NICs. The oldest and newest server each have an additional two cards (four extra NICs on the old server, eight extra NICs on the newest server) while the middle server has one extra card but with 8 NICs on it.